# trouble populating form fields from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Please help!

I'm a complete php/sql newb, and i'm feeling pretty (ok, really) dumb.

I really need help pre-populating text fields of a form i've built for our office staff to contact the workmen in the field, (and the form works well enough); I've searched a million threads, but just could not figure it out...

Only some of the form fields need to pre-populate after a users login, but I have no idea how to make that happen...  I've created a mysql DB with a table called 'users', and i know how to open the DB (and close it), but can't figure out how to pull the data from a given row, and populate the fields I need correctly. here's where I'm at:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXX", "XXXXX") or die("Error connecting to MySQL: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("vendor_sqldb") or die("Error selecting database: ".mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS") or die("Error connecting to table: ".mysql_error());
$rowdetail=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
//1. Add your email address here.
//You can add more than one receipient-
$formproc->AddRecipient('foreman@mysite.com'); //<<--- supervisor email address here

$formproc->SetConditionalField('select field emplyee');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent(employee1,'email@email.com');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent('employee2','email@email.com');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent('employee3','email@email.com');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent('employee4','email@email.com');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent('employee5','email@email.com');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent('employee6','email@email.com');
$formproc->AddConditionalReceipent('employee7','email@email.com');
$formproc->AddFileUploadField('newupload','',1024);//<<------- New file upload
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
if($formproc->ProcessForm())
{
$formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
}
```

And heres the area where I need the help to prepopulate fields:

```
<p align="center">
<label for='email' ></label>
<label for='name' >Office Staff Employee Name* </label>

<input type='text' name='name' id='name' readonly='readonly' 'value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $session->name?>&quot;    name=&quot;name&quot; /&gt;" />
</p>
<p align="center">
<label for='email2' >Your Email Address*</label>
<input type='text' name='email2' id='email2' value='<?php echo $row_Recordset1['email']; ?><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" />
```

I'm not sure how to prepopulate the values for office staffer's name, their email etc?  I supposed that it was a simple echo command, but if it is, I guess I'm not getting the syntax right?
I'm sure im missing a line of code, which would specify row and collumn containing the data too, but don't know how to write this!?

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Can you post more of your code? You make a query for the users but are not using the data. I guess this is just missing code in the question

Comment: Ok sorry, I forgot the echo for the field.value='<?php echo $row_Recordset1['email']; ?><? I'm sure i'm missing a line of code or two to specify row and collumn containing the data too, but don't know how to write this!?!

Comment: You are missing the column names of the table you want to use. I made assumptions in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql selects a row for each user.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS") or die("Error connecting to table: ".mysql_error());
```

You need to specify which user you are trying to get from the database table. I am going to give you an example for the SQL query if the user's names were stored in a column named "USERNAME":

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME='name'") or die("Error connecting to table: ".mysql_error());
```

You can then pull the user specific data and insert it where needed.

Comment: you're way ahead of me; my current USER table only contains the front end employees that send out the forms - these conditional receipents (are the field men) were going to eventually make it into a different table that I was going to call 'VENDORS' to relieve me of making manual updates, but I hadn't gotten there yet -but that's really awesome!   my employee table only contains the office staff that send the field guys out to jobs - that is what i was worried about populating first... do i do that this the same way?  Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the clarification in your comment.